# Why isn't my custom transformer transforming the test set?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a custom transformer for standardizing the code. If I use fit_transform on training set, it works correctly but it only returns NaNs if I apply the transform function on the test test. I have mentioned the code below. Input to the code is a pandas dataframe. Lets say a random 3*3 dataframe with integer values in a range (0, 4). The output that my transform returns is the array of Nans with rows = rows of the test data passed and columns = double the number of colums of the test data with NaNs present everywhere like this

```
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

This is my custom transformer code:

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator

class smooth_score(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.mean = np.mean(X)
        self.std = np.std(X)
        return self


    def transform(self, X):
        X = (X - self.mean) / self.std
        return np.array(X)
```

Comment: can you show your code calling the transformer

Comment: Please do **not** use the comments space for posting code - edit & update your post as needed

Comment: How can I show you the code? Without adding my comment in comment section? @mujjiga

Answer (score 0):

Here's modified version of your code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin

class smooth_score(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.mean = np.mean(X, axis=(0, 1))
        self.std = np.std(X, axis=(0, 1))
        return self


    def transform(self, X):
        X = (X - self.mean) / self.std
        return X

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

tf.fit(df.values)
new = tf.transform(df.values)
```

where `new` is:

```
array([[-1.54919334, -1.161895  , -0.77459667],
       [-0.38729833,  0.        ,  0.38729833],
       [ 0.77459667,  1.161895  ,  1.54919334]])
```

1. `np.std()` and `np.mean()` work per axis, so if you want calculate those across all axes (i.e. get single number, not a 1D vector), you need to specify all axes - hence `axis=(0, 1)` parameter. This should fix your dimension issues.
2. `np.std()` and `np.mean()` will not work on pandas data, thus `df.values` which gets the underlying numpy array. Alternatively, you can use `X.mean().mean()` and `X.std().std()` where `X` is pandas dataframe (double `mean()` and `std()` are not an error!)
3. I would check for `self.std == 0`, that will also give you `NaN`'s